# How can I display a value from a database

Tags: php, mysql

```
            <?php
                $i = 0;
                while ($row = $res->fetchRow()) {
                    $i++;
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input value="<? echo $rows['bookingRef']; ?>">
                </td>
            </tr>

            <?php
                }
            ?>
```

Instead of displaying the value from the database it simply displays " echo $rows['bookingRef']; ". How can I fix this? Thanks

Comment: Use `<?php` instead of `<?`. See [PHP tags](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

Comment: Do you have short tags enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Please change

```
<input value="<? echo $rows['bookingRef']; ?>">
```

to

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $rows['bookingRef']; ?>">
```

It is because you are not defining your tags.